# Showing an analytic function is exactly 0 or never 0 on a domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of analytic function on a connected, open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $f_n \to f$ on compact subsets of $U$. If $f_n(z) \neq 0$ for all $n$ with $z \in U$, show that either $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in U$ or $f \equiv 0$.

Any hint to get started would be appreciated. I'm thinking that it may be helpful to use the fact that if the zeroes of $f$ have an accumulation point then $f \equiv 0$ or if all the derivative of $f$ vanish at a point then $f$ is constant.

Context: I'm studying for a qual in Complex Analysis, so I'd appreciate just a hint at this point.

Comment: Argument Principle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

1. $f_n \to f$ implies $f_n' \to f'$.
2. If $f$ has  zero at $a$ of order $n$ then $n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} d z$ ( $\gamma$ small circle  around $a$).

Comment: I see, you have that the second integral is equal to the limit as $n \to \inf$ of the same integral except replacing $f'$ with $f_n'$ and replacing $f$ with $f_n$ (which is allowed since $f_n \to f$ and $f_n' \to f'$ uniformly on compact subsets, but then we can apply the argument principal to this integral, giving zero (since $f_n$ has no zeroes in the given domain), a contradiction. Does this make sense?

Comment: @m.deslauriers: yes, sounds OK.